# Página dinámica HTML & JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
   <div class="container" style="text-align:center;">
        <h1 class="text-center">Calculate Areas!</h1>
        <div class="init">
            <select name="area" class="form-control">
                <option value="cuadrado">Cuadrado</option>
                <option value="rectangulo">Rectángulo</option>
                <option value="circulo">Circulo</option>
                <option value="triangulo">Triángulo</option>
            </select>
            <button type="button" class="form-control btn btn-primary">Move it!</button>
        </div>
        <div class="meth1" style="display:none;">
            <h3>Area de un cuadrado</h3>
            <input class="form-control" type="number" id="m1">
            <button type="button">Calcular</button>
        </div>
        <div class="meth2" style="display:none;">
            <h3>Area de un rectángulo</h3>
            <input class="form-control" type="number" id="m2">
            <input class="form-control" type="number" id="m2">
            <button type="button">Calcular</button>
        </div>
        <div class="meth3" style="display:none;">
            <h3>Area de un círculo</h3>
            <input class="form-control" type="number" id="m3">
            <button type="button">Calcular</button>
        </div>
        <div class="meth4" style="display:none;">
            <h3>Area de un triángulo</h3>
            <input class="form-control" type="number" id="m4">
            <input class="form-control" type="number" id="m4">
            <button type="button">Calcular</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Lo que quiero es que los div (`meth1`, `meth2`, `meth3` y `meth4`) aparezcan dinámicamente DEPENDIENDO de la selección hecha con el `SELECT` que se ve en el div (`init`), pero lo que quiero es que mientras no se haya seleccionado nada en el `SELECT`, el código no pueda ser visible o "aún no se haya formado".

Lo puedo dejar con el CSS inline de `display:none;` o `display:block;` pero cualquiera puede cambiar la visibilidad fácilmente, y además la carga de la página es mayor debido a que carga todos los cuatro div.

¿Es posible crear el código directamente desde jQuery? Para que sólo se muestre el div `meth1` si en el `SELECT` está "Cuadrado", se muestre `meth2` si en el `SELECT` está "Rectangulo", y así sucesivamente. He leído algo así sobre `createElement` pero no sé.

Comment: No es claro cual es tu problema. Lograr cambiar la visibilidad de los div con el select es facil con jquery. Pero tus requisitos adicionales (" la carga de la página es mayor debido a que carga todos los cuatro div") no me parecen razonables (early optimization...). Tampoco entiendo lo de "cualquiera puede cambiar la visibilidad fácilmente". A que te refieres?

Comment: Mira bien, el código indica que los div dependientes de la respuesta del select están ocultos sólo con css, lo cual es fácilmente editable por cualquier usuario si se muestran los div antes de la respuesta del select, todo se verá ilógico.

Comment: Y qué importa que sea "editable por cualquier usuario"? El codigo HTML siempre es editable, lo mismo que el código Javascript. No entiendo de qué escenario te estás queriendo proteger.

Comment: @leonbloy no estás entendiendo. Vuelve a leer todos lo que cito en esta pregunta, por favor.

Comment: La  verdad no comprendo por qué esta pregunta tiene un -3.

Comment: Cierto. Concuerdo contigo @AlvaroMontoro, por lo que ya le di mi voto a favor.

Comment: @AdrianaHernández gracias

Comment: +1 ! esta pregunta no debería tener votos negativos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si tu preocupación es que el usuario no vea el contenido de los `div` antes de seleccionar nada en el `select`, entonces no sólo no te recomendaría que los tengas con `display:none` y luego lo cambies a `display:block` (algo que tú mismo indicas que no quieres), sino que tampoco te recomendaría lo que has buscado de crear los elementos dinámicamente con JavaScript/jQuery con `createElement`.

El motivo es similar: implicaría que el contenido está disponible en alguna parte en los ficheros JS y el usuario también podría verlo buscando un poco. Podrías ofuscarlo para que sea más difícil de encontrar/leer, pero seguiría estando disponible dentro de los archivos descargados y enlazados por la página.

Para lo que quieres, casi te recomendaría que usases AJAX (directamente con la función [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) o con [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) o [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)). La idea sería poner los contenidos de todos los `div`s (meth1, meth2, meth3 y meth4) en fichero separados (p.e. meth1.html, meth2.html, meth3.html y meth4.html) y eliminar los `div` (dejar sólo uno vacío):

```
<div class="container" style="text-align:center;">
    <h1 class="text-center">Calculate Areas!</h1>
    <div class="init">
        <select name="area" class="form-control">
            <option value="cuadrado">Cuadrado</option>
            <option value="rectangulo">Rectángulo</option>
            <option value="circulo">Circulo</option>
            <option value="triangulo">Triángulo</option>
        </select>
        <button type="button" class="form-control btn btn-primary">Move it!</button>
    </div>
    <div id="meth"></div>
</div>
```

Y entonces añadir un controlador del evento change para el `select` que leerá el contenido del fichero apropiado y lo cargará en el nuevo `div` que creaste. Por ejemplo algo como esto (ojo, no lo he probado y puede contener fallos):

```
$("select[name=area]").on("change", function() { 
    var url = "";

    // decidimos la url a cargar dependiendo del valor del select
    switch ($(this).val()) {
        case "cuadrado":   url = "meth1.html"; break;
        case "rectangulo": url = "meth2.html"; break;
        case "circulo":    url = "meth3.html"; break;
        case "triangulo":  url = "meth4.html"; break;
    }

    // cargamos la url en el div
    $("#meth").load(url);
});
```

Comment: Alvaro siempre me salva,  Jajaja gracias hombre, había pensado también en el AJAX pero creí que habría alguna otra forma, y pues lo de ofuscar suena bien aunque necesito aprender mucho más de JS, voy a intentar cambiar al load, haber qué sucede. Y en cuanto a los votos negativos... La verdad, no tengo ni la menor idea de quien quiera joder mi puntaje ¬¬